# Save Favorite Button State

Tags: ios, swift, button, nsuserdefaults, state

I'm trying to complete my favorite button by saving it state even when i quit the view \ App . it will be great if anyone could show me how can i do this, I'm using Xcode 8 and coding with Swift 3.

## Current Button Code :

```
 //create a new button
        let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        //set image for button
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), for: .selected)
        //add function for button
        Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button), for: .touchUpInside)
        //set frame
        Favoritebutton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 35,height: 35)
        
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
        
        let state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved") ?? false
        
        }


    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true,forKey: "isSaved")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        
        
        
        if let Favoritebutton = sender as? UIButton {
            if Favoritebutton.isSelected {
                // set selected
                Favoritebutton.isSelected = true
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "MY_FAV_KEY")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                
                
                
                  // set badge to tabbar item.
        let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3]
        sel_val = tabItem?.badgeValue
        if(sel_val == nil){
            sel_val = "0"
        }
        let sel_num  = Int(sel_val!)
        tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! + 1) as String
        
        let Fav: NSMutableArray = []
        Fav.add(barImage)
        Fav.add(barName)
        Fav.add(streetName)
        favorite.add(Fav)
        

                
                
            } else {
                // set deselected
                Favoritebutton.isSelected = false
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "MY_FAV_KEY")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            
                
                let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3]
                sel_val = tabItem?.badgeValue
                if(sel_val == nil){
                    sel_val = "0"
                }
                let sel_num  = Int(sel_val!)
                tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! - 1) as String
                let Fav: NSMutableArray = []
                Fav.add(barImage)
                Fav.add(barName)
                Fav.add(streetName)
                favorite.remove(Fav)
                
                
            }
        }
```

As i said,It will be great if anyone could help me save the button's state
even if i quit the view or app , i would really appreciate it, Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Saving the value to UserDefaults writes it out to the plist file.  It does not read the value back in or restore state when the app resumes.  You are responsible for that.  So somewhere in viewDidLoad check the state:

```
let state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved") ?? false
```

Then set your button accordingly

Comment: What do you exactly mean by set your button accordingly? can you help me  with the process ?

Comment: Favoritebutton.isSelected = state . Or anything else that should happen when isSaved is true

Comment: I don't really know how to set this up....Would you mind writing a snippet explaining how can it be done?